# Move Amazon small EC2 instance to large

Tags: amazon-ec2

How would you move your Amazon EC2 small to large instance, considering that small is 32-bit and large is 64bit?

I think there shouldn't be any problem running 32-bit AMI on the 64-bit instance, am I right?

Thank you in adv

Comment: There isn't really any reason to use 32 bit over 64bit at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to run 32bit system on 7,5GB of RAM. 3GB of RAM is usually maximum memory that is reasonable with 32bit system. Linux can use [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) to access more than that but AFAIK PAE in a virtual machine isn't efficient.